# English expression for "charte graphique"

Tags: design, graphics

What is the equivalent english expression for "charte graphique" which is a document that defines the combinations of colours, dimensions and layout for a website?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say "[style guide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Style_guide)."

Comment: +1 I like that even better. Gonna delete my answer.